# Div height 100% to footer not working

Tags: html, css

I have a footer `div` that sits on the bottom with a `min-height: 100%` parent named `#container`. That's working great, but I'm trying to make the `height: 100%` for the `div` named `#content` and I can't seem to get it. Any ideas?

#### CSS:

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
   background: rgb(226,226,226);
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
    padding:10px;
    height: 165px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: rgb(142,0,0);
}
#content {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:100px;
    width:70%;
    left: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: rgb(252,252,252);
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 70%;
    left: 15%;
    background: #1e5799;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `calc()`.. http://jsfiddle.net/vVJGL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7A5fN/3/)

Add a new rule:

```
#header, #footer, #content{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Then add the below to your rule for `#content`, also removing `height:100%`:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:100px; /* <--height of footer */
top:165px; /* <--height of header */
```